# Multi FQL query with limit

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql

I do not know, how get all my threads and last message of each thread by FQL.
I try:

```
fql?q={"threads":"SELECT subject, recipients, updated_time, unseen, unread, thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0", 
"users": "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT recipients FROM #threads)", 
"first_msg": "SELECT message_id, thread_id, body, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM #threads) ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 1"}
```

But ofcouse I get last message only for one (first) thread from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only one answer: add query for each thread to get last message. Plus check max count queries (if present too many threads)